# Developing Website partially in Sharepoint and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Can I develop a part of the website using Content management System(i.e Sharepoint) and few other sections using core ASP.NET ?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please accept it as the answer as Vamsi said previous. Otherwise, it will be hard for you to get help in the future because no one will want to spend time answering a question that will be of no benefit to them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. A sharepoint website can contain asp.net pages and run them. Just build your web app and put the asp.net pages in a directory that can be accessed by your site, create the pages in sharepoint using the aspx files and put the dll file your app spits out in the bin directory of your sharepoint site.